# How to save (and retrieve) NSAttributedString in a NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, nsattributedstring

I am trying to save and retrieve XML data to a file.

For this purpose I am using `NSDictionary`'s `writeToFile:`
The question is, how to write and retrieve an attributed string to and from a file on disk using `NSDictionary`'s `writeToFile:`?

Comment: You can't - at least not directly. You need to convert the `NSAttributeString` into something that can be written to a file.

Comment: BTW - is this iOS or OSX? It might make a difference.

Comment: well I am writing an OSX app...

Answer (score 4):

If you need something more portable than archived object consider using RTF representation of NSAttributedString:

```
    NSAttributedString* attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Attributed String" 
        attributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [NSColor redColor]}];
    NSData* rtfData = [attrString RTFFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length) documentAttributes:nil];
    [rtfData writeToFile:@"string.rtf" atomically:YES];
```

You can read it back:

```
    NSData* rtfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"string.rtf"];
    NSAttributedString* attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithRTF:rtfData documentAttributes:nil];
```

Also since RTF is a simple text format you can convert RTF data to NSString and store it as plain text in a dictionary.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I still couldnt make to work for me! I have class with properties of types NSString, NSNumber, bool and NSAttributedString. I need to write this structured data (instances of this class) to be written on disk to be accessed later.

Comment: well... I am sorry to bother you again, but here is my problem. I have a class lets say class 'A' with all the NSStrings and NSAttributedStrings... Then I have another lets say class 'B' which has an NSMutattablearray of objects of type class 'A'. Now  I want to be able send the message to class 'B' to write all the instances of class 'B' (which are present in its array) to disk. And 'B' should also be able to read back the objects from the file back to its array of objects of class 'A'

Comment: Please read this as there's no easier way to explain this: [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html)

Both A and B classes should conform to `<NSCoding>` protocol.

Answer (score 2):

`NSAttributedString` is not [a property list object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH44-SW2), so `writeToFile:` won't work.

It does, however, conform to `NSCoding`, so you can [write it to an archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000949-BABGBHCA) with your dictionary as the root object (assuming that all the other objects in the dictionary also conform).

Comment: can't i simply convert everything (string and attributes) to the file as a string, and afterwards take the entire string and read it in an NSAttributedString object?

Comment: Sure you can, but an `NSKeyedArchiver` will already do the work for you. Are you concerned with the file being human-readable in some way? You'll have to write up your own conversion of `NSAttributedString` in that case. If you wrote a method to represent an attributed string as an `NSDictionary` for serialization, you could then use `writeToFile:`

Comment: Could you show me an example please? Can I use it on my own classes, or do I have to have NSDictionary for this to work?

Comment: If you want to use `writeToFile:`, you'll have to somehow represent the `NSAttributedString` in one of the property list types; `NSDictionary` is just one of those classes. You could also use an `NSString`. It's just going to be a matter of extracting the attributes from the string and putting them in your chosen representation. As another option, you could use `NSKeyedArchiver` to convert each `NSAttributedString` to an `NSData` object, which is a property list type; then you could use `writeToFile:`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is very late here right now, I have a class early morning, I will try it after my class and report back :)