# Can we add NSMutableAttributedString to NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdictionary, nsattributedstring

Can we add `NSMutableAttributedString` to `NSDictionary` ?

```
NSMutableAttributedString *text;

        text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:CommonLS(@"PromoCodeForSignInPart1")
                                                      attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithSize:12 light:YES],
                                                                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];

        [text appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:CommonLS(@"PromoCodeForSignInPart2")
                                                                     attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithSize:12 bold:YES],
                                                                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor], NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor giftCardBannerViewLabelTextColor]}]];

        [text appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:CommonLS(@"PromoCodeForSignInPart3")
                                                                     attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithSize:12 light:YES],
                                                                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}]];

NSDictionary *dealDictioinary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Congratulations!",kKeyDealTitleText,text.string,kKeyDealSubTitleText,kKeyDealTypeFlightSearch,kKeyDealType, nil];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add explanation of code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: Yes you can. But you aren't. You want `text` not `text.string`

Comment: see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312708/how-to-save-and-retrieve-nsattributedstring-in-a-nsdictionary